# Custom array class in C++

Tags: c++, array

I wrote a custom array class in C++ to suit my personal use case. The main important rule in this project is that no unassigned element is allowed between 2 assigned elements; please review for improvement:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <limits>

template <typename T>
class Array {
public:
    size_t ofs_to_pos(size_t ofs);
    size_t pos_to_ofs(size_t pos);

    Array();
    Array(size_t size);
    ~Array();

    void resize(size_t newSize);
    void extendBy(size_t val);
    void shrinkBy(size_t val);
    void shrinkToFit();
    void del();

    void assign(T val, size_t ofs);
    void fill(T val);
    void push(T val);
    void unshift(T val);

    void deassign(size_t n);
    void clear();

    void insert(T val, size_t ofs);
    void append(T val);
    void prepend(T val);
    void load(const T *src, size_t srcLen, size_t ofs);

    void remove(size_t ofs);
    void pop();
    void shift();

    bool empty();
    bool full();

    Array *clone();
    const T& operator[] (size_t ofs);
    const T *getBuf();
    size_t getLen();
    size_t getSize();
private:
    T *buf;
    size_t len;
    size_t size;
};

template <typename T>
size_t Array<T>::ofs_to_pos(size_t ofs)
{
    if (ofs == SIZE_MAX)
    {
        return ofs;
    }
    else
    {
        return ofs + 1;
    }
}

template <typename T>
size_t Array<T>::pos_to_ofs(size_t pos)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        return pos;
    }
    else
    {
        return pos - 1;
    }
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array()
{
    buf = nullptr;
    len = 0;
    size = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(size_t size)
{
    buf = new T[size];
    if (!buf)
    {
        this->size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this->size = size;
    }
    len = 0;
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete buf;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::resize(size_t newSize)
{
    if (newSize == size)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (newSize == 0)
    {
        delete buf;
        buf = nullptr;
        len = 0;
        size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        T *blk = new T[newSize];
        if (blk)
        {
            if (len > newSize)
            {
                len = newSize;
            }
            if (!empty())
            {
                std::memcpy(blk, buf, len * sizeof(T));
            }
            delete buf;
            buf = blk;
            size = newSize;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::extendBy(size_t val)
{
    if (SIZE_MAX - val < size)
    {
        return;
    }
    resize(size + val);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::shrinkBy(size_t val)
{
    if (val > size)
    {
        return;
    }
    resize(size - val);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::shrinkToFit()
{
    resize(len);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::del()
{
    resize(0);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::assign(T val, size_t ofs)
{
    if (ofs > len || ofs == size)
    {
        return;
    }
    buf[ofs] = val;
    if (ofs == len)
    {
        len += 1;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::fill(T val)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = val;
    }
    len = size;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::push(T val)
{
    if (len < size)
    {
        assign(val, len);
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void Array<T>::unshift(T val)
{
    assign(val, 0);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::deassign(size_t n)
{
    if (n > len)
    {
        return;
    }
    len -= n;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::clear()
{
    len = 0;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::insert(T val, size_t ofs)
{
    if (ofs > len)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (len == size)
    {
        T *blk = new T[size + 1];
        if (!empty())
        {
            std::memcpy(blk, buf, ofs * sizeof(T));
        }
        if (ofs < len)
        {
            std::memcpy(blk + (ofs + 1), buf + ofs, (len - ofs) * sizeof(T));
        }
        delete buf;
        buf = blk;
        size += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ofs < len)
        {
            std::memmove(buf + (ofs + 1), buf + ofs, (len - ofs) * sizeof(T));
        }
    }
    buf[ofs] = val;
    len += 1;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::append(T val)
{
    insert(val, len);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::prepend(T val)
{
    insert(val, 0);
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::load(const T *src, size_t src_len, size_t ofs)
{
    if (src_len == 0 || ofs > len)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (len + src_len > size)
    {
        T *blk = new T[len + src_len];
        std::memcpy(blk, buf, ofs * sizeof(T));
        std::memcpy(blk + ofs, src, src_len * sizeof(T));
        if (ofs < len)
        {
            std::memcpy(blk + (ofs + src_len), buf + ofs, (len - ofs) * sizeof(T));
        }
        delete buf;
        buf = blk;
        size = len + src_len;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ofs < len)
        {
            std::memmove(buf + (ofs + src_len), buf + ofs, src_len * sizeof(T));
        }
        std::memcpy(buf + ofs, src, src_len * sizeof(T));
    }
    len += src_len;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::remove(size_t ofs)
{
    if (ofs >= len)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (ofs < (len - 1))
    {
        std::memmove(buf + ofs, buf + (ofs + 1), (len - ofs) * sizeof(T));
    }
    len -= 1;
}

template<typename T>
inline void Array<T>::pop()
{
    if (!empty())
    {
        remove(len - 1);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::shift()
{
    remove(0);
}

template<typename T>
bool Array<T>::empty()
{
    return (len == 0);
}

template<typename T>
bool Array<T>::full()
{
    return (len == size);
}

template<typename T>
Array<T> *Array<T>::clone()
{
    Array *arr = new Array(size);
    arr->load(buf, len, 0);
    return arr;
}

template<typename T>
const T& Array<T>::operator[](size_t ofs)
{
    return buf[ofs];
}

template<typename T>
const T *Array<T>::getBuf()
{
    return buf;
}

template<typename T>
size_t Array<T>::getLen()
{
    return len;
}

template<typename T>
size_t Array<T>::getSize()
{
    return size;
}
#endif
```

Comment: This looks more like a vector (resizable) rather than an array (fixed-size).  In any case, you forgot to tell us what's special about your use case (given that `std::vector` has no mechanism to permit uninitialised values in its content).

Comment: One thing not mentioned yet in answers, but is too little to warrant an answer of its own, is the missing documentation and comments. For example, what is the difference between "len" and "size"? You need to read the code to understand this, you can't just look at the class declaration and guess. You also need a big warning saying that `T` must be POD (and probably a `static_assert` as well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The copy-constructor doesn't copy any of the content, so we get a double-free in the destructor - running your unit-tests under Valgrind should demonstrate that.

We're missing at least

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>

using std::size_t;
```

Personally, I don't recommend `using` in headers - write the type in full, and don't pollute the user's global namespace.

The interface is too different to the standard container interface - it can't be used by generic algorithms.  The lack of iterators is particularly constraining.

I recommend getting rid of the memory management completely, and instead wrapping a standard container (probably `std::vector`) to provide robust memory management for you.

Answer (score 8):

### Overview:

- Construction done badly.
- No Assignment operators.
- Destruction done wrong
- No thought given to move semantics.
- Copying data in C++ is not the same as C.
  We use constructors. So we can't just copy raw memory.

### Advice:

This code is very broken.

- Go learn the rule of three/five.
- Read my article on [vectors](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Vector-ResourceManagementAllocation).

### Code Review

Not sure what these are for!

```
size_t Array<T>::ofs_to_pos(size_t ofs)    
size_t Array<T>::pos_to_ofs(size_t pos)
```

---

Use Initializer list in constructrrors.

```
template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array()
{
    // Don't do this
    // This is a bad habit that will cause your app to do twice as much
    // work when the types have constructors and assignment operators.
    buf = nullptr;
    len = 0;
    size = 0;
}
```

---

Again use the initializer list.

```
template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(size_t size)
{
    buf = new T[size];
    // This will never return nullptr
    // So the first part of the if is never executes.

    // Note 1: new will throw an exception if it can allocate memory
    // Note 2: this constructs all the 'T`
    //         If you are handling size and len separately, this is a
    //         terrible idea as you are wasting resources initializing
    //         objects that may never be used.
    if (!buf)
    {
        // This is never executed.
        this->size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this->size = size;
    }
    len = 0;
}
```

---

You are using the wrong `delete`.

```
template <typename T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
     // This deletes a single object.
     // You allocated an arrray of objects.
     // use:  delete [] buf;
    delete buf;
}
```

---

This only works if `T` is a POD type.
Otherwise it is broken.

```
template<typename T>
void Array<T>::resize(size_t newSize)
{
    if (newSize == size)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (newSize == 0)
    {
        delete buf;
        buf = nullptr;
        len = 0;
        size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Note: Again you are constructing all the objects
        // You probably don't want to do that. Its not effecient.
        T *blk = new T[newSize];
        if (blk)
        {
            if (len > newSize)
            {
                len = newSize;
            }
            if (!empty())
            {
                // This is illegal if the `T` has a constructor.
                // You need to use the assignment operator.
                //
                // Note: If you fix the problem with constructing all the
                //       members on allocation then you should use the
                //       construct in place operation.
                std::memcpy(blk, buf, len * sizeof(T));
            }
            delete buf;
            buf = blk;
            size = newSize;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Suddenly you use `inline`!!

```
template<typename T>
inline void Array<T>::unshift(T val)
{
    assign(val, 0);
}
```

The keyword `inline` has no real meaning in modern C++ (apart from to prevent linking issues). As this is in a header file (and not in the class) all the functions should be marked `inline` (not to do actual inlining but to let the linker know there will be more than one definition and it needs to remove the extra ones).

---

Again the use of `memcpy()` is invalid if `T` is not a POD.

```
template<typename T>
void Array<T>::insert(T val, size_t ofs)
{
    if (ofs > len)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (len == size)
    {
        T *blk = new T[size + 1];
        if (!empty())
        {
            std::memcpy(blk, buf, ofs * sizeof(T));
        }
        if (ofs < len)
        {
            std::memcpy(blk + (ofs + 1), buf + ofs, (len - ofs) * sizeof(T));
        }
        delete buf;
        buf = blk;
        size += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ofs < len)
        {
            std::memmove(buf + (ofs + 1), buf + ofs, (len - ofs) * sizeof(T));
        }
    }
    buf[ofs] = val;
    len += 1;
}
```

Comment: My knowledge of C++ is fragmented so obviously I have a lot to learn and lots of gaps to fill

Comment: @machine_1 Read my four articles on writing a vector. That will walk your through the basics.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the observations made by @TobySpeight, the parameter names `pos` and `ofs` are less readable and maintainable than `position` and `offset`, while `pos` might be okay, `ofs` for `offset` is not very clear.

Without some include `std::memcpy()` does not compile.

As Toby Speight indicated, it isn't clear why you created this rather than using `std::vector`. It is also very very concerning that there are no iterators to improve the performance.